# How to pass a nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers

Below is a simplified example of the code I'm working on. There's a function that takes class A pointer as an argument. I want to pass a pointer that has been initialized as nullptr. Without initializing it to some garbage temporary value first, is it possible to pass the nullptr?

```
class A
{ 
    // stuff
};

class B
{
public:
    A* pA1;
    A objA;
    std::vector<A*> vecB;
    B() : pA1 (nullptr) { vecB.push_back(&objA); }
};

void function(A* p);

A* pA2;

int main()
{
    B objB;
    pA2 = objB.vecB[0];
    function(objB.pA1);

    return 0;
}

void function(A* p)
{
    p = pA2;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do in your program.

Comment: The point of the function is to make this happen:  objB.pA1 = pA2

Comment: Note that the `p` inside the definition of `function` is its own pointer initialized from a *copy* of the argument you passed.  So assigning it will only have an effect inside `function`, and no effect on any other pointer object.  If you wanted to modify another pointer, you would need something like `void function(A*& p)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you said:

> The point of the function is to make this happen: `objB.pA1 = pA2`

I think what you need to do is pass a reference to the pointer, instead of passing a pointer by value. Use:

```
void function(A*& p) // The argument type needs to be "A* &", not "A*"
{
    // Now, the change will be visible in the calling program.
    p = pA2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any raw pointer type can be assigned and therefore initialised with the `nullptr` value. Example:

```
static A* pA2 = nullptr;
```

Comment: The pointer that I'm passing has already been initialized as nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

aschepter has given me the answer in a comment, thank you very much.

```
void function(A* p)
```

should be

```
void function(A*& p)
```